# Use of foldr vs foldl in defining length

Tags: haskell

I know that **foldr** can be used to define a length function on the list [1,2,3,4] like this:

```
ghci > foldr (\x y -> 1 + y) 0 [1,2,3,4]
```

and that it works like this:

```
Starting accumulator = 0
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
Answer = 4
```

But I am unsure why the equivalent **foldl** function evaluates to 5 not 4:

```
ghci > foldl (\x y -> 1 + y) 0 [1,2,3,4]
```

---

How I think it work from chi's hint:

```
Starting accumulator = 0 (not used) 
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 4 = 5
Answer = 5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

```
> foldl (\x y -> 1 + y) 0 [1,2,3,400]
401
```

Also note that these two function types take arguments in a different order:

```
> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> :t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @WillSmyth No. `foldl` takes its arguments in reverse order so when you write `\x y -> 1 + y` you're adding 1 to the element being processed and not the accumulator. That's why in chi's example it gives 401.

Comment: Sorry Is that not what I am showing in my answer? I am not using the accumulator and the answer is not carried over.

Comment: @WillSmyth Your last update looks OK: at every step you discard the accumulator and return the current list item + 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually define your length function (call it `length'` or something) and ask GHCi for its type using `:t length'`, you will see that it does not have the type you would expect. If you define it with the correct type signature, `length' :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`, the type error should give you a hint about what you did wrong.